# Javascript with Safari doesn't work - all other browser do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script which duplicates the form fields when a "Same as Billing" checkbox is clicked from one form to another.  It works fine except in Safari it won't transfer the state selection from the original form.  The form field for the state is a select box.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#same").click(function(){
        if($("#same:checked").length >= 0) {
            $('#first_name_ship').val($('#first_name_bill').val());
            $('#last_name_ship').val($('#last_name_bill').val());
            $('#address1_ship').val($('#address1_bill').val());
            $('#address2_ship').val($('#address2_bill').val());
            $('#city_ship').val($('#city_bill').val());
            var selected_state = $('#state_bill_select   option:selected').val();
            $('#state_ship_select option[value=' + selected_state + ']').attr('selected','selected');
            $('#zip_ship').val($('#zip_bill').val());
```

Comment: Did you try using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
.prop('selected', true)
```

instead of

```
.attr('selected','selected');
```

which might work better with safari in general.

Try that out.